# Adium is displaying only Facebook contacts who message me first

Tags: facebook

When I look at my Facebook contact list in Adium, I can see only people who write to me first. When I enable *show offline contacts* I can see all of them displayed as offline, however when I go directly to Facebook, many of them are displayed online.

I've done little search and it looks like many people are having issues with Facebook chat in Adium, but I didn't find any fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you setup your account using the "Facebook chat" wizard?

If so, you can delete this account, it's not working anymore since Facebook enabled to Jabber access.

You should try to create a *Jabber*-type account and enter those informations:

- Username: *your_facebook_username*@chat.facebook.com
- Password: same as your Facebook profile
- Server: chat.facebook.com
- Port: 5222
- Use SSL

You can find more details on the [Facebook Chat **about page**](http://www.facebook.com/sitetour/chat.php).